# Mixing Architectures?

Tags: c++, architecture, fortran, linker-errors

I have a Fortran DLL that is used in my C++ program in which I am getting `LNK2001` errors.

I checked the Fortran DLL build and it is supposedly 64 bit while my C++ code is in 32 bit.

This is the problem to my linker errors correct? (This is being asked because I have already checked to ensure that the fortran lib is added to my project correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't combine 32 and 64 bit in one executable.

Comment: Ok. That's what I was suspecting. Thanks.